# Select node in XML with value from list using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a list of possible attribute values and I want to select all nodes which contains one of this values

Here is an example XML:

```
.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv generator-info-name="Rytec" generator-info-url="http://forums.openpli.org">
  <channel id="TVP1.pl">
    <display-name lang="pl">TVP 1</display-name>
  </channel>
  <channel id="TVP2.pl">
    <display-name lang="pl">TVP 2</display-name>
  </channel>
 <programme start="20171128001000 +0100" stop="20171128004500 +0100" channel="TVP1.pl">
    <title lang="pl">Gol Ekstra</title>
    <sub-title lang="pl">[magazyn piłkarski]</sub-title>
    <desc lang="pl">Skrót najważniejszych wydarzeń z rodzimych boisk piłkarskich. Program prowadzą na zmianę Rafał Patyra i Maciej Iwański. W każdym odcinku pojawi się gość związany ze światem piłki nożnej</desc>
  </programme>
  <programme start="20171128004500 +0100" stop="20171128022000 +0100" channel="TVP1.pl">
    <title lang="pl">Jak ona to robi</title>
    <sub-title lang="pl">[KOMEDIA]  (I Don't Know How She Does It) (2011) (USA) [od 12 lat]</sub-title>
    <desc lang="pl">Boston. Kate Reddy (Sarah Jessica Parker) jest finansistką w dużej korporacji. Jej mąż, architekt Richard (Greg Kinnear), pracuje w domu. Para wychowuje dwoje dzieci: sześcioletnią Emily (Emma Rayne Lyle) i młodszego
Douglas McGrath
Sarah Jessica Parker, Pierce Brosnan, Greg Kinnear, Christina Hendricks
Filmweb: 5.5/10
IMDb: 4.8/10</desc>
  </programme>  
</tv>
```

I'm able to select all nodes with value:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/tv/channel[@id='TVP1.pl']" rytecPL_Basic.xml
```

I've got a list of "channel" like "Polsat.pl,TVP1.pl,TVP2.pl" and want to select nodes which contains one of this channels, sth like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/tv/channel[@id=IN('Polsat.pl,TVP1.pl,TVP2.pl')]" rytecPL_Basic.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *Xpath* boolean **`or`** operator (ensures any one of the condition to be satisfied):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/tv/channel[@id='Polsat.pl' or @id='TVP1.pl' or @id='TVP2.pl']" -n rytecPL_Basic.xml
```

The output:

```
<channel id="TVP1.pl">
    <display-name lang="pl">TVP 1</display-name>
  </channel><channel id="TVP2.pl">
    <display-name lang="pl">TVP 2</display-name>
  </channel>
```